# JSON API request in PHP not working Properly

Tags: php, json, api

I'm struggling to retrieve data from an API using PHP.

My PHP code:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.coronavirus.data.gov.uk/v1/data?filters=areaName=United%2520Kingdom;areaType=overview&structure={%22areaName%22:%22areaName%22,%22date%22:%22date%22,%22newCasesByPublishDate%22:%22newCasesByPublishDate%22,%22cumCasesByPublishDate%22:%22cumCasesByPublishDate%22}");

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo $output;
?>
```

Sadly this just outputs a random list of characters like this:

```
��9|_��M�\�E�JЀ���"�H*p�Kx���,:VK�`>���m��a˒��܆�V^��gt�d�e]���������������f�ӷ�7�?_�\=�^Z)�b�j��߽�����������{����������tu�������7����+/J���~���������>������o>|�y�v�����s��Et{���i��L;�+>�Pq�F7��ĵQ�u�q9s��e��*͈f hkh�T����Ӵn�ճ�4�Dk�4��E��q��J����XUi�4-r��j�9UZB���s)�J9��a&�z�� �$�Ͳ��n &��4����� �a* ��UP�:Gz�4В:�Z�Pc�@KZsښJU'���mĔ3�@Kj�4KSU�@Kꜧ7�ڇ��ZR����ZUyݨ2I����`�֭�ӴQ�u-Y{JZX�i�%5*dwZ�;����4�Ű�FI�%A��3�������E�u��{@�e@TZm�uWidsVm� j�˱�`�V$��hrz�\���4�������Fǜ��%˩e�xQ��J-F�*�к�m��.��Q��y�m��2�4�+ݚJ��Ts�R�(!Ge�t���\��F�e���)� �kȤ�ZN4Tf��-���ςhَ&*���T�ɕ����ZA �R."��0�Y�#��Ԓ-��ֿ0�l#?թL�Uj��l,$�+md��t0�ȒLv�VM����f�$Abm�L#%)�hU�d�Sf�ݬ�vL�FǼ�k�VE�ܔ�%Y�/z�n��c�=UE&35��yd $3`�ʲ>jf��֬t�E��TvY��׬��(@"]�9%�u��4�'E���U�utQcК�}�T��*�浨0�J%T�Z� ��AkVr�kFj����iL ��0�+S��Y�H9�>u���S�O�S�I0��|�95-���g���Q +1d(HHԮ�Y�M=���IM�i8���T�PA��Ta�Ԇ��O���$*%�2����o�aU<��h��RR�2�.�@��cf�aT�8��JkF �!�O#y&����h$˔ #׎���yς�&è� ��|DO�;Z��$X3U��2yX�b��e��0��Ȩ�4���ZT<�iCK�D�t�i��D���m���Pa� k!����D3&^��������e֔i�2:��s�4�j��*��]z�3�G�tT�g<.�&7����V����^yY٦N$9�%���TF�a?ÿ�T׍��Q���e��6�w2�~L��m� �C�E��@wԏV^�7l5�uk�DPixZ\˅Ny��6�'���"�d�ͭ�5lj��}�J��88��Z�J���S�Ir5V��g�M��#[cx�5�}M�:��k{Suo� \7˔i�%��[�=BUe�U�p���%U��V]@[my�Z��.�V�*���z�4����݇�]�R^&�V�� o� �ɜ&^stS^(&���ʁv�W�p}l�\T)��]�@;�f *��S�U�YD�������\%��ft��*�(���ZO�z���@G�͐6L9*O�W�-[Qu�S������L��n��݊��B�sJ���M�Q����>�+ �F�)9�|��f7?�D�ó�%��Ҁ�������al6m�c#GUǄ(�pyl䨖Z��cVS�q�O�t�PV��1I�j��%Ŭ��F���(�*�)�7�h%�*�U��\����VA�ڠ�~Fл��{k����Rh�b{���i�nv��M� |Ƙhf-TZ����{���&6�z��uW��UC��&�7kC�����D�n��T3�i�.�'��6��w1���,M��B{7e�r@M��81��м�Tc���]TiDR�G�Y K5���`���d��9�G�%����=�r(Й �W���Zx���q�@�^�P���b Oi�S1� &���sB@��sF#G�oB�M(e U�_�26��M(� %6��M(�99�Y�?T�mB)爲J�']N3*��W���7��93&S��}W)mJ݄�P��O1l=����U]�>]_� �[��V��(��V���n�@�h+e�����R�Jl+e�����R�Jl+e�����R���2����l�e+e([)C�J��������7W��ǫ����w������_��}u�������������ot�����������������˻����W��?<�?}��t�|ֿ~����_��_/��}����_��>~۩ώ?����S�=��<}w��������5-��_��_fk��������ç�����m��3W��ߦ���x����⶷nx
```

Putting the url directly into a browser works fine, giving a nice JSON, see [see here](https://api.coronavirus.data.gov.uk/v1/data?filters=areaName=United%2520Kingdom;areaType=overview&structure=%7B%22areaName%22:%22areaName%22,%22date%22:%22date%22,%22newCasesByPublishDate%22:%22newCasesByPublishDate%22,%22cumCasesByPublishDate%22:%22cumCasesByPublishDate%22%7D).

I'm really scratching my head to know where to go from here to get this to parse properly in PHP.

Can anyone help, I'm completely out of my depth here.

Comment: have you tried adding curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_ENCODING , ""); ? https://myprogrammingnotes.com/uncompress-gzip-encoded-content-php.html

Answer (score 1):

**Excellent....thank you soooo much !!!!!**, you have just solved a problem I have been trying to sort out on-and-off for some time.

Answer (score 0):

The retrieved data is encoded, to enable decoding, add this line.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
```

This enables the decoding of the retrieved data, by using and empty string as parameter, it enables all encoding types.

With the line added, your code will look like this.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.coronavirus.data.gov.uk/v1/data?filters=areaName=United%2520Kingdom;areaType=overview&structure={%22areaName%22:%22areaName%22,%22date%22:%22date%22,%22newCasesByPublishDate%22:%22newCasesByPublishDate%22,%22cumCasesByPublishDate%22:%22cumCasesByPublishDate%22}");

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, ''); // <--- ADDED LINE!
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need just encoding, this is working code:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.coronavirus.data.gov.uk/v1/data? 
filters=areaName=United%2520Kingdom;areaType=overview&structure{%22areaName%22:%22areaName%22,%22date%22:%22date%22,%22newCasesByPublishDate%22:%22newCasesByPublishDate%22,%22cumCasesByPublishDate%22:%22cumCasesByPublishDate%22}");

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo $output;
?>
```